# Applying two separate pure CSS3 animations on a button element

Tags: html, css

I need to run two CSS3 animations on a button element (ideally in pure CSS, semi-ideally in cross-browser, vanilla JS) for a web mobile application of mine.

The first is a bulge-out-and-in animation; it's to play when the button element loads.

The second is a spinning animation applied on the button element; it's to play when the button is tapped.

Know that tapping the button causes the page to refresh. So the idea is that the user would see the button spin after tapping it, and then have it bulge-out-and-in (exactly once) after the page reloads.

However the behaviour is erratic. Ergo, I'm seeing the bulge animation fire multiple times (in succession).

If I exaggerate this bulge-out, it seems to only play once, but there's a visible shiver in the button before it plays (almost as if the animation is firing and aborting midway multiple times).

I can't tell why this is happening. Can you help me accomplish this cleaninly without shenanigans?

---

```css
button.refresh:focus {
  -webkit-animation: rotation 0.5s 20 linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}

@keyframes bulge {
  0% {
    transform: scale( 1);
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale( 1.1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale( 1);
  }
}

.load {
  -webkit-animation: bulge 0.5s 1;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="/">
  <button class="refresh load" style="background-image: url('{{ static_url }}img/refresh.png')" type="submit" name="rf" value="1">&nbsp;</button>
</form>
```

p.s. ignore the `{{ }}` type syntax - that's a Django framework thing.

Comment: Probably because browsers that support it prefer animation over -webkit-animation. you might want to use only one, so that the button.refresh overrides the other one?

Comment: not able to reproduce the issue, the animation happens only once for me (which is logic) which browser did you test ?

Comment: @SourceOverflow: pardon that mixup. The problem persists if I use `-webkit-animation` (or just `animation`) throughout.

Comment: or maybe you lose the focus before the page load

Comment: @TemaniAfif: well if I lost focus, that still shouldn't cause the 'bulge' animation to run twice right (since it's essentially defacto called `onload`). What could be a cleaner way to do this so that I sidestep all these shenanigans?

Comment: @HassanBaig What happens is when the button loses focus, the conditions for `animation: rotate` are no longer true, so the animation goes back to its default value, which is `bulge`. Not sure how to get around that.

Comment: @MrLister yes true, but the focus is not lost before reload, are you able to reproduce the issue ? as am not ..

Comment: @TemaniAfif If you add another button, you can switch between those with Tab and shift+Tab and see the focus and unfocus events in action. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/57ubr58s/). Note I also took the liberty to exaggerate the bulge a bit, because it wasn't very visible otherwise.

Comment: After further testing, I realize it would be wrong to say the animation plays *twice*. I just exaggerated the bulge animation - to blow up the button to a huge size (over 5s). That huge-bulge-out-and-in anim only played **once**. However, right before it played (or right after the spinning animation), I saw a state where the button was growing small and large (by a small fraction) really fast, almost as if it was shivering or the animation was kind of stuck. Earlier, I mistook this shiver to be the anim playing twice (since the original anim had a small amplitude as well).

Comment: @MrLister yes but you are switching between both buttons which is not the case here :) in this case we will never lose the focus as the page reload immediatly